# Why is my MySQL connection disconnecting although autoReconnect is true?

Tags: java, mysql

Sometimes my MySQL connecting disconnects after 8 hours (standard wait_timeout value). And everytime I get the following error:

[Server thread/WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 432,896,866 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 432,897,054 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

It says that i have to set autoReconnect to true, but this is how I connect to MySQL:

```java
final Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.setProperty("user",user);
prop.setProperty("password",password);
prop.setProperty("useSSL","true");
prop.setProperty("autoReconnect","true");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+database,prop);
```

As you can see: autoReconnect is enabled, so why is my connection disconnecting and how can i fix that?

Comment: What version of MySQL and Connector/J are you using?

Comment: MySQL Version: 10.3.22-MariaDB

Comment: How can I check my Connector/J version?

Comment: Do you use an application server? Which one? Or your application is standalone? In this case, it should be the version of the dependency.